# Detecting when assembly info version not updated

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, f#-fake

I'm using Git as my source control and team city for running builds which compile a .net code base using FAKE script.

We want to be able to detect as a build check if someone has changed a library without bumping the version number. 
Not all changes in the repository will require a new version of a nuget package to be created, only if a library which is packaged changes its version number.

This approach has a human error element to it of changing the library, but forgetting to bump the version and therefore it not being published.

Comment: Have you tried doing `git show` and then grepping for file names to see if the ones under library folder are there, but the version file is not?

Comment: Will that just show the last change, team city sometimes bundles comits into a single build.  I have found FAKE can tell you what files have changed from team city. I will investigate and report back.

Comment: If you can get the list of commits from Team City, you can `git show` all changes from first to last.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go.